# How can I access mobile broadband from my USB stick?

Tags: 12.04, networking, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I can't access the internet using my usb modem on my laptop. While I can access the internet from my PC. Both are running Ubuntu 12.04.

What can I do to detect the problem?

**Here the result of lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6461 Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 19d2:0033 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM246
```

Bluetooth)
    Bus 002 Device 005: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
    Bus 002 Device 006: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
    Bus 002 Device 007: ID 413c:8160 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 365 Bluetooth

**And here the reult of sudo lshw -class network**

```
PCI (sysfs)  
  *-network                   
description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:12:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 70:f1:a0:a0:00:00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.2.0-37-generic firmware=N/A ip=172.16.4.55 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:fbc00000-fbc03fff

*-network  
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:13:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 02
   serial: a4:ba:d0:c0:f0:f0
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:45 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0b10000-d0b10fff memory:d0b00000-d0b0ffff memory:fb200000-fb21ffff
```

The result of `tailf /var/log/syslog` after plugging the modem in

```
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 NetworkManager[911]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB3) starting connection 'MobiNil Default 1'
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 NetworkManager[911]: <info> (ttyUSB3): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 NetworkManager[911]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB3) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 NetworkManager[911]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB3) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 NetworkManager[911]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB3) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 modem-manager[885]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0: state changed (registered -> connecting)
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 modem-manager[885]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0: state changed (connecting -> registered)
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 NetworkManager[911]: <warn> GSM connection failed: (32) No cause information available
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 NetworkManager[911]: <info> (ttyUSB3): device state change: prepare -> failed (reason 'unknown') [40 120 1]
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 NetworkManager[911]: <warn> Activation (ttyUSB3) failed.
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 NetworkManager[911]: <info> (ttyUSB3): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 NetworkManager[911]: <info> (ttyUSB3): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 NetworkManager[911]: nm_system_iface_flush_routes: assertion `ifindex > 0' failed
Feb  8 13:32:14 Inspiron-N5010 NetworkManager[911]: nm_system_iface_flush_addresses: assertion `ifindex > 0' failed
```

Answer (score 1):

ZTE 3G modems sometimes come as "dual media", they act as a CD on power on.

Here is what works for me: (best open two terminal windows)

In one terminal type `tailf /var/log/syslog` to watch what happens
in the other type `eject sr1` (that should disable the CD mode and get the system to recognize it as modem).

After some time (I see when the activity in syslog gets slow again) I am able to use `network-manager` to connect to my 3G-provider.

Comment: Here is the result of tailf /var/log/syslog when I connect [output is here](http://pastebin.com/buFj2BQ4), and it is already recognized as modem ?

Comment: Is there anything else I can do, to check the problem cause and fix it ?

Comment: In the part of `/var/log/syslog` you posted I only see that the modem seems to be recognized, so my guess was wrong. Did you somewhere enter the correct connection details from your provider?

Comment: I did entered it correctly as their customer service told me ?